# A question on Smale-Birkhoff homoclinic theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, ergodic-theory, chaos-theory

Does Smale-Birkhoff homoclinic theorem ("given a transverse homoclinic intersection for a diffeomorphism $f$, there exists an integer $n \geq 1$ such that $f^{n}$ has an invariant Cantor set on which it is topologically conjugate to a shift on $N$ symbols") imply the existence of infinitely many $\textbf{distinct}$ homoclinic orbits?

My reasoning being is that then $f^{n}$ will have an countable infinity of saddle periodic orbits, each with their homoclinic intersections... is this right?

Comment: Do you actually try to answer any of your numerous questions? Besides that bad policy to ignore replies that you don't like...

Comment: I did state my reasoning above - plus where did I ignore replies? @JohnB

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many distinct homoclinic orbits, caused by the secondary intersections of the stable and unstable manifolds of the fixed points. It follows from the lambda-lemma.